# Can a sonar quality profile be set when analysing a Github Pull Request with SonarQube Github Plugin?

Tags: github, sonarqube

Does anyone know if the plugin https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/GitHub+Plugin works correctly if using a custom Quality profile for a project? Apparently it looks like even though I have setup from the Sonar server a different Quality Profile for my project, the default one is still being used, as seen from the logs:

```
[org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubeTask] Quality profile for java: Sonar way
```

With sonar.profile option being deprecated, how does the GitHub plugin works in this case when we have custom Quality Profile setup for a project?

Answer (score 0):

When analysing a Pull Request, the quality profile that will be used is always the same as the one configured for the project in the web application (or the default one if none has been explicitly set in the UI).

So if you get this message and you think that you customized the quality profile for your project, chances are that this is not exactly the same project you're looking at. One of the reasons might be that you don't have the exact same project key (for whatever reason).